# Error: Projects(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm facing this problem, and have no idea how to solve. I'm following a tutorial, and i check several times the code, but i could't solve it.
If anyone can help, thank you.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { useSelectedProjectValue, useProjectsValue } from "../context";

export const Projects = ({ activeValue = null }) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(activeValue);
  const { setSelectedProject } = useSelectedProjectValue();
  const { projects } = useProjectsValue();


  return (
    projects &&
    projects.map(project => (
      <li
        key={project.projectId}
        data-doc-id={project.docId}
        data-testid="project-action"
        className={
          active === project.projectId
            ? "active sidebar__project"
            : "sidebar__project"
        }
        onKeyDown={() => {
          setActive(project.projectId);
          setSelectedProject(project.projectId);
        }}
        onClick={() => {
          setActive(project.projectId);
          setSelectedProject(project.projectId);
        }}
      >
        {("Project", JSON.stringify(project))}
      </li>
    ))
  );
};
`´`
```

Comment: what happens if you console log the value of 'projects'?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are returning nothing because there are no project. You can remedy that by telling the component what to return if there are no projects. For example a string that says  'no projects'.

```
return (
projects ?
projects.map(project => (
      <li
        key={project.projectId}
        data-doc-id={project.docId}
        data-testid="project-action"
        className={
          active === project.projectId
            ? "active sidebar__project"
            : "sidebar__project"
        }
        onKeyDown={() => {
          setActive(project.projectId);
          setSelectedProject(project.projectId);
        }}
        onClick={() => {
          setActive(project.projectId);
          setSelectedProject(project.projectId);
        }}
      >
        {("Project", JSON.stringify(project))}
      </li>
    ) 
:  <li key='empty'> No Projects</li>
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the attention Josh. I found the problem, in another component i was typing a value out of syntaxe: I was typing this way: value={( projects, setProjects )} The correct one is: value={{ projects, setProjects }}